# C++ if statements with strings only give one answer

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, compare, std

So, im trying to write a text adventure thing, and whenever I try to compare a string with a message, I will always get the same output, no matter what I write... I have searched and searched, and cannot find an answer... I have experience programming with Java, LUA, and a bit of HTML... Maybe what I am attempting to do is too similar to the Java way of things? Well, here is a little bit of the code that might end up helping out a bit.

```
string sex;

cout << "Would you like to be a boy or a girl?" << endl;
cin >> sex;
cout << sex;
//statement to declare what you are...
if (sex == "boy" || "Boy"){
    cout << "You have chosen to be a boy!" << endl;
}
else if (sex == "girl" || "Girl"){
    cout << "You have chosen to be a girl!" << endl;
}
else{
    create();
}
```

Any sort of help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: strings in c are different. try using [`strcasecmp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcasecmp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
if (sex == "boy" || sex == "Boy"){
    cout << "You have chosen to be a boy!" << endl;
}
else if (sex == "girl" || sex == "Girl"){
    cout << "You have chosen to be a girl!" << endl;
}
```

to

```
if (sex == "boy" || sex == "Boy"){
    cout << "You have chosen to be a boy!" << endl;
}
else if (sex == "girl" || sex =="Girl"){
    cout << "You have chosen to be a girl!" << endl;
}
```

The reason is `if (sex == "boy" || "Boy")` statement, second part will always evaluate to be true.